# Sum of Square Error

Tags: regression, self-study, mathematical-statistics

Is anyone familiar with the formula for the sum of squares error and how to apply it using the numbers given? Looking online, the formulas I found didn't seem to apply well so I'm wondering if this is a multi-step type of problem.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, actually it's very easy. you should compare the formula of $s^2$ (only $s$ is given in your exercize) to the one of SSE.

The solution is:

> $s^2 \cdot (120-2) = 32214737.5$

In your text it is reported rounded to unit.

Comment: I just realized there is enough information to compute it also from s.d. of y and R2

Comment: Thank you!  So the formula would be S^2*(n-2) = SSE? How would you compute it with s.d of y and R2?

Comment: Yes, 2 there is the number of degrees of freedom. Actually, $s^2$ is computed starting from SSE, so that formula is the reverse of what you will generally find. Also $R^2$ is computed from proportion of SS of y and SSE, so you can find SSE reversing the formula of $R^2$: $s_y^2(n-1)(1-R^2)=SSE$

Comment: thank you sir! much appreciated

Comment: you are welcome! would you mark the answer as acepted?